# Calculation of one-loop diagram in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, feynman-diagrams, wick-rotation

In Folland's book *Quantum Field Theory*, page 207, he gives the value of the amputated one-loop $\phi^4$ diagram as
$$I(p) = \frac{(-i\lambda)^2}{2} \int \frac{-i}{-q^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon} \cdot \frac{-i}{-(q+p)^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon} \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4}. \tag{1}$$
To evaluate this integral, he first Wick rotates by substituting:
$$q^0 \rightarrow iq^0 \\ p^0 \rightarrow ip^0$$
which he claims gives
$$\frac{(-i\lambda)^2}{2} \int \frac{-i}{(|q|^2 + m^2)(|q+p|^2 +m^2)} \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4}. \tag{2}$$
He then goes on to introduce Feynman parameters and carries on with the computation. I am confused on the numerators of (1) and (2). After carrying out the multiplication of the two fractions in (1), shouldn't the numerator of (2) be $-1$? Also, how is it justified to drop the terms containing $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am confused on the numerators of (1) and (2). After carrying out the multiplication of the two fractions in (1), shouldn't the numerator of (2) be $-1$?

Don't forget that you have a $dq_0$ in your measure $d^4q = dq_0 d^3q$.

So you pick up another factor of $i$ when you make the $q_0\to i q_0$ substitution (change of variables), since $dq_0 \to i dq_0$.

> Also, how is it justified to drop the terms containing $\epsilon$?

It is justified to set $\epsilon$ to zero because the rest of the denominator can no longer be zero. For example, there is no way for $|q|^2 + m^2$ to be zero since both terms are non-negative, and $m^2$ is positive (since $m\neq 0$).

The $\epsilon$ is there to make the integration meaningful when the denominator can be zero, and it is understood that we want $\epsilon$ to go to zero. So, after the Wick rotation we can just explicitly set $\epsilon$ to zero, since that is the same as the limit as it goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked how the measure transforms under the Wick rotation.